# Change URL depending on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a language switcher to a specific html page. I don't need any language text only the link to another site will need to be changed depending on the click.
It wouldn't make much sense here to create three html pages just to deal with some link change but my jquery skills are not that great.

The destination structure looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a  class="clickButton" href="folder1/firstLink/Languages/English/folder/index.html">Index Link</a></li>
<li><a  class="clickButton" href="../folder2/secondLink/Languages/English/folder/index.html">A different Link </a></li>
<li><a  class="clickButton" href="../../folder3/Languages/English/folder/index.html">Another different link</a></li>

<ul>

<ul>
<li><a  class="clickButton" href="folder1/firstLink/Languages/Spanish/folder/index.html">Index Link</a></li>
...
<ul>
```

As you can see I would only need to replace the language name ("English") with Spanish in order to make the link work.
So I was thinking that the user clicks on the according flag and the url string changes accordingly.

I would be happy about some example how to switch the language name

Answer (score 1):

*HTML:*

```
<a data-lang="Spanish">To Spanish</a>
<a data-lang="Russian">To Russian</a>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var current = "English"
$("[data-lang]").on("click", function() {
    var lang = $(this).data("lang");
    $(".clickButton").prop("href", function(i, href) {
        return href.replace(current, lang);
    });
    current = lang;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/a2xqL/

Answer (score 1):

make it easy for yourself: add custom data attribute to links;

```
<a data-lang="English" href="">
```

Than access it with jQuery by `$link.data('lang');` and add it to the href.