# Jquery - Change URL depending on click or selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a follow-up question to my previous post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895416/change-url-depending-on-click)

I want to change the string of a url depending on the selected language.
So if I have `href="../folder/Languages/English/test/test.html`

clicking or selecting another language would change the href to: `href="../folder/Languages/SomeOtherLanguage/test/test.html`

Now I want to add a flag-icon according to the language. Since I couldn't find a way to create this with css I stumbled over the jQuery-plugin [ddSlick](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick). I like the overall style of the plugin but now I can't get it to work with the text link solution.
I have set up a jsfiddle so you can have a look: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bJPwn/)

Maybe this is easier than I think it is but my jQuery is not good enough for this.

Hope you can help me out here.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly got want you want but I have changed something in the fiddle. I hope that's thing you want. Check the new [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mQt7P/) out

Comment: you did it the reverse way :-) The links above were the initial setup. So that you can see that the three links below will change the Language in the href. Now I want to select the language with jquery (wih the select box) and change the three links accordingly.