# Dropdown-Box Setup

Tags: jquery, html

this question is related to my previous post about changing the URL of an href-tag when clicking on some switch.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910487/jquery-change-url-depending-on-click-or-selection)

I now have set up something different since I couldn't get anywhere. 
The href-changing now works but I cannot get the selected icon plus name to show in the dropdown-box.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hH8EQ/)

So for example if "German" is selected then it should appear with the according flag icon as the current selection in the dropdown-box.

Is my setup wrong or what does it take to fix this?

```
 <div id="language-selection"><div id="current-language"><span class="element-invisible">Current language:</span>
      <img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_United_Kingdom.png" alt="English" title="English" /> English
  </div>
  <div class="element-invisible">Switch to:</div>
  <ul id="other-languages">
  <li class="zh-hans first"><a  href="javascript:;"  data-lang="Chinese" class="clickButton"><img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_China.png" alt="简体中文" title="简体中文" /> 简体中文</a></li>
  <li class="en"><a  href="javascript:;"  data-lang="English" class="clickButton" </a> <span class="language-link"><img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_United_Kingdom.png" alt="English" title="English" />English</span></li>
  <li class="de last"><a href="javascript:;"  data-lang="German" class="clickButton"><img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_Germany.png" alt="German" title="German" /> German</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>   

<ul>
    <li><a class="clickButton" href="folder1/firstLink/Languages/English/folder/index.html">Index Link</a></li>
    <li><a class="clickButton" href="../folder2/secondLink/Languages/English/folder/index.html">A different Link </a></li>
    <li><a class="clickButton" href="../../folder3/Languages/English/folder/index.html">Another different link</a></li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add code given below in your jquery script code before `current = lang;`

```
   /*Replace language flag src , alt and title*/
   $('#language-selection > #current-language > img').attr('src' , $(this).find('img').attr("src"));

   $('#language-selection > #current-language > img').attr('alt' , lang);
   $('#language-selection > #current-language > img').attr('title' , lang);

   /*check for all content in div having id current-language and check if nodeType == 3 mean string text then replace old text with new one */  
   $("#language-selection > #current-language").contents().each(function() {
         if(this.nodeType == 3)
             this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(current, lang);
     });
```

Please check link [Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hqPYC/).

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi I changed your code a little bit in order to work. You need to change both language text and language image on select click.

HTML part :

```
<div id="language-selection"><div id="current-language"><span class="element-invisible">Current language:</span>
      <img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_United_Kingdom.png" alt="English" title="English" /><span class="text">English</span>
  </div>
  <div class="element-invisible">Switch to:</div>
  <ul id="other-languages">
  <li class="zh-hans first"><a  href="javascript:;"  data-lang="Chinese" class="clickButton"><img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_China.png" alt="简体中文" title="简体中文" /> 简体中文</a></li>
  <li class="en"><a  href="javascript:;"  data-lang="English" class="clickButton"><img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_United_Kingdom.png" alt="English" title="English" />English</a></li>
  <li class="de last"><a href="javascript:;"  data-lang="German" class="clickButton"><img class="language-icon" src="http://www.euromonitor.com/medialibrary/Image/Flag_20x20_Germany.png" alt="German" title="German" /> German</a></li>
</ul>
 </div>   
...
```

JS in this part :

```
 ...
 var current = "English"
$("[data-lang]").on("click", function() {
    var lang = $(this).data("lang");

$(".clickButton").prop("href", function(i, href) {
        return href.replace(current, lang);
    });

    $("#current-language img").attr("src", $(this).children("img").attr("src")); // NEW 

    $("#current-language .text").text(lang); // NEW

    current = lang;
});
```