# Jquery Browser Back Button - Keep Settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this question is based on my previous question here at
[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007293/dropdown-box-setup) where I wanted to change the href link depending on a language selection.

Thanks to the help here it now does what it should.

```
(function ($) {

$(function(){
var select = $('#language-selection');

var options = select.children('#other-languages');
select.attr('style', '-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;');
options.css({
display:'none'
});

select.click(function() {
if(options.css('display') == 'none') {
/* options.css({display:'block'}); */
options.slideToggle('fast');
} else {
/* options.css({display:'none'}); */
options.slideToggle('fast');
}
});

});

})(jQuery);


    var current = "English"
$("[data-lang]").on("click", function() {
    var lang = $(this).data("lang");

    $(".clickButton").prop("href", function(i, href) {
        return href.replace(current, lang);
    });


$('#language-selection > #current-language > img').attr('src' , $(this).find('img').attr("src"));

$('#language-selection > #current-language > img').attr('alt' , lang);
$('#language-selection > #current-language > img').attr('title' , lang);


$("#language-selection > #current-language").contents().each(function() {
    if(this.nodeType == 3)

             this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(current, lang);

});



current = lang;

});
```

My Question is: When following a link that got changed with the language selection and the browser back button is clicked it will of course go back to the default language setting.

Is there an easy way to "save" the language setting so that it won't switch back to the default?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to store it in localStorage when the user changes the value :

```
var lang = $(this).data("lang");
localStorage['lang'] = lang;
```

And when you load a page, you can do

```
var lang = localStorage['lang'] || defaultLanguage;
```

So you don't have to pass the chosen language in URL and it stays saved on the user's computer.

BTW, I prefer to use [normalized language codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes), that is "en" instead of "English", for the compatibility with various i18N tools.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are on the same page about my setup or what I need to do to get your solution working. See this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/7yt3d/)